# How to get the count from joined table when grouping by on the first

Tags: sql, join, count, group-by

I have two tables `Fact` and `Dimension`. Dimension contains two fields `ID` and `ObjectID`. Fact contains `DimensionKey` which join to the `ID` in Dimension. `ID` is unique but `ObjectID` is not. This is a versionning mechanism. All rows having the same `ObjectID` are actually different versions of the same object.

I am trying to find the count of all `Facts` pointing to all versions of `Dimensions` for a certain object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly try

```sql
SELECT d.objectid, COUNT(*) total_facts
  FROM fact f JOIN dimention d
    ON f.dimentionkey = d.id
 GROUP BY d.objectid
```